# ServiceStack captures HTTP 500 internal error from Kestrel?

Tags: servicestack, kestrel-http-server

I have a self-host app basing on [ServiceStack.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Core/)(v1.0.44),  the `ServiceStack.AppSelfHostBase` from [ServiceStack.Kestrel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Kestrel/)(v1.0.44) internally relies on Kestrel http server to serve the requests.

The app works fine in my local machine. but it returns an ambiguous HTTP 500 error when it is compiled and deployed by our building server.
[image]

After investigating for hours, I found the reason is assembly redirection.  Because ServiceStack lazy loads the AspNetCore and other assemblies, there is no error generated on startup.  And the HTTP 500 error happens before my code execution when it is trying to load some assembly. There is no logs at all.

My quick fix is to include all the signed assemblies in the app.config file's `assemblyBinding` section.

```
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework.SqlServer" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="1b44e1d426115821" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="1.2.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="1.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="6.10.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NewRelic.Api.Agent" publicKeyToken="06552fced0b33d87" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="6.18.139.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="protobuf-net" publicKeyToken="257b51d87d2e4d67" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="2.3.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ServiceStack.Interfaces" publicKeyToken="e06fbc6124f57c43" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.AppContext" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="1.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Console" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="1.0.106.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="1.0.106.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="1.0.106.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.StackTrace" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Globalization.Calendars" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.FileSystem" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq.Expressions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Sockets" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection.Metadata" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="1.4.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Principal.Windows" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.RegularExpressions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.9.9.9" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

After adding all the assemblies's redirection, the problem is solved. But still I don't know which assemblies were causing this error.
**My question is: How to capture this kind of error in ServiceStack when it failes to lazy-load the assemblies?**

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack isn't doing any lazy loading, .NET is naturally only going to load the dependencies when it runs code that uses those dependencies. If you use the dependencies in your AppHost `Configure()` it will force their use on Startup so you can do something like resolving a Service and executing a test request, e.g:

```
using (var service = container.TryResolve<MyServices>())
{
    var response = service.Any(new MyRequest());
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work,  there is no exception thrown in startup from above code.  but after that,  the HTTP 500 error still occurs unless I put back all the `assemblyBinding`

Comment: It’s not going to prevent needing any necessary assembly bindings, it’s just an example of showing how you can Execute a Service on Startup. It’s unlikely the same code works on Startup will fail at runtime since this is an App configuration issue. You may not be using the right dependency which throws the Exception on first use.

Comment: Thanks @mythz, I am aware assembly bindings are necessary,  but I want to find out the exact mismatched assemblies.  Currently it only returns HTTP 500 error,  there is no exception occurs and hard to tell which assemblies are mismatched.